# My email sign up form submits but when it doesn't collect the emails

Tags: javascript, function

So I recently learn how to code using udemy I bought some in depth courses on html,css and javascript. So i really don't know what information to include to fix my problem.

my thought process is that either I got a conflicting functions or a function doesn't load all the way so the information doesn't have time to be sent

```
$( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function ( e ) {

        e.preventDefault();
```

his is the only other function that I have that I think would conflict with the reason I am not getting emails.

to honest I don't grasp the concept of javascript as well as I do html and css.

If my question can't be answered I understand because I don't even know what information to provide! btw im using

form method="post"

I don't know if that makes it more helpful

Comment: Currently your question is not very clear as to the issue you are experiencing. Be detailed in explaining every step and include what you expect to happen vs what is actually happening. It would be helpful to share the html and the entire javascript file you

Answer (score 0):

Hey to do a form post like you want you might do something like this

```
<form>
  <input type="email">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var email = $(this).find('[type="email"]').val()
    $.ajax({ AJAX INFORMATION HERE })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand this script can you explain what its doing. This is what I am doing in the form <form method ="post" class="af-form-wrapper" role ="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action= "https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"